# ActionViewError:Missing Template inside controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, simple-form

So, i have 2 forms. In one of them, im submitting the form to the method "create", the default one created with resources:

```
resources :correlation_engine_rules
```

In this form, i just link the form with the path via simple_form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(:correlation_engine_rule, url: correlation_engine_rules_path, :html => { :remote => true, :method => :post }) do |f| %>
```

Now, if i submit, im calling the method called "create" in my controller:

```
def create
    ...things happening...

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rule.save
        format.html { redirect_to correlation_engine_rules_path(value: @cep_status), notice: "#{I18n.t('controllers.rule_created')}" }
        format.js { flash[:notice] = "#{I18n.t('controllers.rule_created')}" }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html do
          redirect_to correlation_engine_rules_path(@rule),
                      alert: @rule.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| "<li>#{msg}</li>" }.join
        end
        format.js
        format.json { render json: @rule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The rule is saved and the page is redirect to that path. This is working. Now, i wanted to have a new form, with another method controller to process these new fields.

So, i created new routes:

```
resources :correlation_engine_rules do
      get :basic_rule_2, on: :collection
      post :create_basic_rule_2, on: :collection
end
```

And then i associated the new form with my new method controller (create_basic_rule_2):

```
<%= simple_form_for(:correlation_engine_rule, url: create_basic_rule_2_correlation_engine_rules_path, :html => { :remote => true, :method => :post }) do |f| %>
```

When i submit, the controller is called correctly, the problem comes when doing the exact same redirect as before. Here the redirect fails and it tried to render a view called "create_basic_rule_2", which i don't understand. I'm telling him to redirect to correlation_engine_rules_path as before.

```
def create_basic_rule_2
    ...things happening...

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rule.save
        format.html { redirect_to correlation_engine_rules_path(value: @cep_status), notice: "#{I18n.t('controllers.rule_created')}" }
        format.js { flash[:notice] = "#{I18n.t('controllers.rule_created')}" }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        Rails.logger.error "\n\n\n\ NO GUARDADO"
        format.html do
          redirect_to correlation_engine_rules_path(@rule),
                      alert: @rule.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| "<li>#{msg}</li>" }.join
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

What bugges me is that is the exact same code, and the path is the same wherever you are, so why create is not render a view called "create", but my method create_basic_rule_2 is trying to render a view called "create_basic_rule_2?

Here is the error that i get:

```
<ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template correlation_engine_rules/create_basic_rule_2, application/create_basic_rule_2 with {:locale=>[:es, :en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/opt/rb/var/www/rb-rails/lib/modules/vault/app/views"
  * "/opt/rb/var/www/rb-rails/lib/modules/social/app/views"
  * "/opt/rb/var/www/rb-rails/lib/modules/monitor/app/views"
  * "/opt/rb/var/www/rb-rails/lib/modules/location/app/views"
  * "/opt/rb/var/www/rb-rails/lib/modules/ips/app/views"
  * "/opt/rb/var/www/rb-rails/lib/modules/flow/app/views"
  * "/opt/rb/var/www/rb-rails/lib/modules/correlation_engine_rule/app/views"
  * "/opt/rb/var/www/rb-rails/app/views"
  * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.5.10/app/views"
>
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered as it does not have a reproducible example which shows the behavior you are asking about. It would also help if you didn't truncate the error message.

Comment: Why is my controller method trying to render a view called the same? how can i stop that from happening?  The 2 methods have the same redirect, one is working but the other is not. I cannot tell you how to reproduce this because i also don't know what is the problem or what is the cause.

Comment: "how can i stop that from happening?" - rendering, redirecting or returning false will prevent rails from implicitly rendering. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ImplicitRender.html

Comment: "I cannot tell you how to reproduce this because i also don't know what is the problem or what is the cause." - And you expect someone who doesn't know what you are doing, has not seen the actual code that triggers the error to know whats going on? If you can't do the basic steps of whittling the problem down there is nothing anybody can do but guess wildly.

Comment: One method is trying to render a view with the same name, but the other is not, although the code is the same. Maybe someone knows why this is happening although he can't not reproduce the error. I know what you are saying but it's not the first time i see people getting answers without properly specifying what is the problem, so i wanted to try my luck here, that's it.  Anyway i edited my question in case its more clear now, but that's pretty much all, there is no more code involved in my error.

Comment: Yes, conceptual questions ("How do I do X?") can be answered without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But this is a tried and true debugging question ("Why isn't my code code working?") and you need to do the work and isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setup a MRE and check the request type (hint its on the first line of the logs) of the request you can see that the issue is actually pretty straight forward:

```
<%= simple_form_for(:correlation_engine_rule, url: create_basic_rule_2_correlation_engine_rules_path, :html => { :remote => true, :method => :post }) do |f| %>
```

Rails UJS defaults to sending those pesky `application/javascript` AJAX requests when you set the [`data-remote="true"` option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements).

Which means that the controller is actually executing this block:

```
format.js { flash[:notice] = "#{I18n.t('controllers.rule_created')}" }
```

Since it does not render or redirect rails will implicitly try to find a template named `create_basic_rule_2`. Redirecting in `format.js` response won't actually do anything since its an AJAX request.

Instead you want to set `remote: false`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(:correlation_engine_rule, url: create_basic_rule_2_correlation_engine_rules_path, html: { remote: false, method: :post }) do |f| %>
```

Which will just submit the form normally and trigger the `format.html` block.

If you really wanted to send an ajax request and cause a redirect you would have to create a template and set `window.location`:

```
# views/controller_name/correlation_engine_rule.js.erb
window.location = '/new_location'
```

Comment: Yes, problem was with the remote: true, changing to remote false fixed the problem. Still i'm kind of surprised this error doesn't happen in the other form, where i also have remote: true, anyway thanks a lot.